# Sending bitmap with keeping transparency in android

Tags: android, sockets, bitmap, arrays

I'm encountering a problem when I try to send bitmap with transparent background through sockets in Android.

The bitmap in displayed with transparent effect on the server app

I get the bitmap, compress it to PNG this way:

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 60, stream);
```

and when receiving I decode bitmap:

```
streamBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
```

and draw it:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(streamBmp, 0,0 , null);
```

The bitmap is displayed on the client but without transparency. It was replaced by white color.

How can I keep transparency when sending bitmaps in Android?

Comment: it has nothing to do with sending the data, whats your Bitmap's Config ?

Comment: Thank you for help.
I found my mistake, I was drawing a white background and not a transparent one.
Sorry, Silly question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your bitmap config is ARGB_8888

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html